# Anyway to only show ::after pseudo element if the tag has any content in it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an empty `<h1></h1>` and in the CSS I have targeted it with a pseudo-element `::after content: 'this is some text'`  the pseudo elment still shows content even if there is no content in the `<h1>`.

My question is how can I hide and only show the pseudo-element when the `h1` is populated and hide it if there is not content in the   `<h1>`.

I am changing the `.innerText`  with javascript to the `<h1>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [:empty](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#empty-pseudo) pseudo class to differentiate between elements with content and elements without content.

```css
h1:not(:empty)::after {
  content: "pseudo-content";
}
```

```html
<h1>Test with content</h1>
<h1></h1>
```